# ExtJS View creation

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have the following view:

```
Ext.define("FI.view.InstallBaseList", {
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
require: 'FI.store.InstallBaseStore',
title: 'List',

alias: 'widget.installBaseList',

icon:'table.png',

store:'FI.store.InstallBaseStore',

columns: [],

divId:'',
    dockedItems: [],
height: 200,
width: 700,
renderTo: "container",
enableLocking: true,
draggable: true,
resizable: true,

 initComponent: function(config){
         console.log("here");
    }
});
```

and this is how I try to create it from a controller:

```
list = Ext.widget('installBaseList', params);
```

In the browser I get this error:

```
me.dockedItems.insert is not a function
addDocked(items=[Object { xtype="header", title="List", titleAlign="left", more...}], pos=0)    ext-all-debug.js (line 47051)
updateHeader(force=undefined)    ext-all-debug.js (line 90398)
beforeRender()    ext-all-debug.js (line 90275)
getRenderTree()    ext-all-debug.js (line 26056)
render(container=Object { dom=div#container, id="container", $cache={...}, more...}, position=undefined)    ext-all-debug.js (line 26193)
constructor(config=Object { divId="container", columns=[0]})    ext-all-debug.js (line 44380)
callParent(args=[Object { divId="container", columns=[0]}])    ext-all-debug.js (line 3728)
constructor(config=Object { divId="container", columns=[0]})    ext-all-debug.js (line 56387)
constructor ()    ext-all-debug.js (line 3892)
widget(name="installBaseList", config=Object { divId="container", columns=[0]})    ext-all-debug.js (line 5083)
(?)()    ListCo...5323863 (line 98)


me.dockedItems.insert(pos + i, item);    ext-all-debug.js (line 47051)
```

What is more, in the `initComponent` method, `config` seems to be undefined. Why?

Where lies the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The initComponent method must contain a call to callParent in order to ensure that the parent class' initComponent method is also called.

Here is the fix http://jsfiddle.net/nscrob/EcX3Q/11/

also you don't need to sent the parameter config to the initComponent, The object config has been already assigned to the component and can be accessed by this. So if you have:
Ext.create('...',{mode:add}); in init component you will have this.mode = add;

Comment: Thank you. Can you please also tell me why `config` appears as undefined in the `initComponent` method?

Comment: here is an example of what i'm saying and probably your config looks rather the same http://jsfiddle.net/nscrob/EcX3Q/13/

Comment: You sir, are a life saver! Do you know by any chance a method to set the Panels's columns on creation(in initComponent maybe)?

Comment: you can just add them to the config you are sending, they need to be under the attribute columns, or you can modify them in initComponent in this.columns but before you call parent. Here is the example http://jsfiddle.net/nscrob/EcX3Q/21/. By the way you made my day :)